# align left figure caption in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

figure captions in R markdown to PDF are centered by default. here's an example:

```
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---


![Caption](test_pic.jpg)
```

(where `test_pic.jpg` is a local jpg file)

any ideas how to align the caption left?

I found how to change the size, using special attributes:

```
![Caption](test_pic.jpg){#id .class width=30%}
```

but what's the special attribute to align left?

Comment: Please place a sample of the R markdown. I'm assuming (by the antiquated font) that this is a PDF but not all R markdown files produce PDFs so it would help the latex-rmarkdown-ers help you faster (and, perhaps, add a latex tag)

Comment: done...........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, to align the caption left in PDF output from Rmarkdown we can use one chunk per image, with `knitr::include_graphics` in the chunk to display the image (this creates the LaTeX for the image), and a little LaTeX that controls the alignment of the caption:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
    pdf_document:
        includes:
            in_header: file.tex
---

Here are some examples of `knitr::include_graphics` with the code chunk options being used to control the size and location:

```{r fig.align="left",  out.width = "50%", fig.cap="left-aligned"}
knitr::include_graphics("rrtools-steps-carbon.png")
```

```{r fig.align="center",  out.width = "30%", fig.cap="center aligned"}
knitr::include_graphics("rrtools-steps-carbon.png")
```

```{r fig.align="right",  out.width = "20%", fig.cap="right aligned"}
knitr::include_graphics("rrtools-steps-carbon.png")
```
````

And here is `file.tex`, which should be in the same directory as the RMarkdown file:

```
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=normal,up,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
```

And here's a screenshot of part of the output:

[image]

Comment: thanks! is there any resources where I can learn what the arguments in the TeX file mean? I need one chunk per image, right? I can't have one chunk for several images (since the caption is in the header of the chunk)?

Comment: yes, one chunk per caption. Though you could have multiple images produced by one chunk. As for a resource... google? Honestly, LaTeX is might as well be a bunch hopeful incantations to me, and I usually end up getting them from https://tex.stackexchange.com after googling